# Given a field $F$ and two non-zero elements $x,y\in F$, does there always exist $\theta \in F$ st. $\theta x+(1-\theta)y=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is,

> Given a field $F$ and two non-zero element $x,y\in F$, does there alwasy exist $\theta \in F$ st. $\theta x+(1-\theta)y=0$?

This is definitely true if $F=\Bbb R$. Anyone can help with the general case? Thank you!

Comment: You can just solve for $\theta$, provided $x\ne y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=y$ your equation become $y = 0$ which is false. So your equation is wrong.